# Torrent malware

Tags: security, bittorrent, hacking

After I downloaded some courses from a 3rd party website I found that there is some of the data had uploaded automatically .

- how can I know which data has been uploaded.
- is that some kind of malware or stealing data?
- is that normal?
- what should I do if it was malware ?
  here is an image that shows that 3.59GB of data has been uploaded:

[image: image.png]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Unrelated to Ubuntu, I guess the "uploaded" data is you seeding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you were seeding parts of your torrent files to other users. Seeding is sharing parts of files that people want to download. When you download a file, you are downloading pieces of the file from other users on the network. They are seeding parts of the file to you. When you seed to other users, you are basically allowing others to download the files you have downloaded.

Think of it as giving back to the community.

Comment: thank you ...that make sense ...that mean this website Depends on decentralization data???